# Changing child instance variable in overriden method

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

Basically, I have code that boils down to the below. When run, I expect the following output:

```
Parent doing work
Child overriding. variable=5
Child overriding. variable=10
Child childMethod(). variable=10

Parent doing work
Child2 overriding. variable=5
Child2 overriding. variable=10
Child2 childMethod(). variable=10
```

What I get is the following output:

```
Parent doing work
Child overriding. variable=0
Child overriding. variable=10
Child childMethod(). variable=5

Parent doing work
Child2 overriding. variable=0
Child2 overriding. variable=10
Child2 childMethod(). variable=10
```

My theory for this mismatch is that `variable` gets used "before" it is declared. This is based on

1. `variable` has its initial value set to `0` according to the output (int default)
2. In the case of the class `Child`, `variable` seemingly regains its supposed initial value of `5`.

Is this correct, that `variable` gets used "before" it is declared? Also, is there any reasoning behind why this is the expected behaviour?

---

```
public static void main(String[] params) {
    Parent child = new Child();
    child.childMethod();

    System.out.println();

    Parent child2 = new Child2();
    child2.childMethod();
}

public static abstract class Parent {

    public Parent() {
        method();
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Parent doing work");
    }

    abstract void childMethod();
}

public static class Child extends Parent {
    int variable = 5;

    @Override
    public void method() {
        super.method();
        System.out.println("Child overriding. variable=" + variable);
        variable = 10;
        System.out.println("Child overriding. variable=" + variable);
    }

    public void childMethod() {
        System.out.println("Child childMethod(). variable=" + variable);
    }

}

public static class Child2 extends Parent {
    int variable;

    @Override
    public void method() {
        super.method();
        System.out.println("Child2 overriding. variable=" + variable);
        variable = 10;
        System.out.println("Child2 overriding. variable=" + variable);
    }

    public void childMethod() {
        System.out.println("Child2 childMethod(). variable=" + variable);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is bad code design. You should not try to explain it, just forget it.

Comment: Likely already answered many times - have you searched about behavior of calling virtual method from constructor?

Comment: The overridden method `method` is called before the variable `variable` is initialized. Use a debugger to see what happens step by step. To avoid situations like these, only call final methods in constructors.

Comment: brummfondel: by understanding it, I will not repeat it. By not repeating it I will write better code.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov: no, I did search for explanations but I didn't know what to search for. Thank you for your suggestion, it will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. The child class is only initialized after the parent class is finished construction. Inspecting or modifying the child state during the parent's constructor means you're interacting with uninitialized fields.

In your case, you're reading the default value of 0, and your changes are discarded once the child initializes.